# How to sort fields in jasper report

Tags: sorting, jasper-reports

I have a list of bean (JRBeanCollectionDataSource) and the goal it's to export it in pdf. But the list should be sorted by the field 'name'.

I can export it in pdf, but it's not sorted.

I have found nothing, just the 'sort component'.

Here is an excerpt of the code :

```html
 <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <field name="fistname" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fistname]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <detail>
  <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField pattern="#,##0.00;-#,##0.00">
    <reportElement x="758" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="bbb4c112-0026-4043-9aca-987d1cecf7c9"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font size="6"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement x="27" y="0" width="225" height="20" uuid="5ab06ade-3b0f-463d-b30d-877592c8cf2b"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font size="7"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fistname}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </detail>
```

Can you tell me how to sort this list in ireport?

Comment: It would be helpful to add more details on what you have tried already. Some code snippets if existing might also be of help.

Comment: You have two fields named 'nom' - are you sure you want that? That being said, consider the use of sortField.

Comment: Sorry, it's an error which is corrected.

Comment: Ok. Then use sortField as also shown in @jjlema's answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the element "sortField" and that element needs to come after any "field"-elements you may have in your report. Not just the one you are sorting on, but *really* last.

```
<field name="personName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tokenName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="serviceName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<sortField name="serviceName" />
```

Default sort order is "Ascending". You can override this by adding the attribute "order" with the value of "Descending". ( Note the capital D )

```
 <sortField name="serviceName" order="Descending"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list, probably you have defined a subdataset with the fields of your list, and there you have the sortField property:

```
<subDataset name="mySubdataset">
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fistname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <sortField name="fistname"/>
</subDataset>
```

Comment: In all my jrxml i don't have this subDataset. I have it only in a subreport and it's empty :<subDataset name="dataset1"/>. I tried to test your subDataset, but nothing change :S.

Comment: I have not used the list element, i simply used the fields which i put directly in the detail band (by slipped Filed).

Comment: Hello,I'm going a little bonkers over this seemingly trivial task. I don't use a subdataset. I have created sort fields, and they show up under my `<jasperReport ...>` tag. Do these `<sortField ...>` tags have to be nested in a specific level?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. There is no need to put the tag ' subDataset ' . You just have to add the tag ' sortField ' and it works correctly. Thank you all