# How to sort data grouped by in subDataset using another filed e.g. nameLast?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to sort the existing dataSet which is already groupedBy pId. I tried sortField but it's applied before groping, in fact, the expected is first groupBy then sort.

Here is my subDataSet & datasetRun:

```
<subDataset name="currentDuesDataSet" uuid="c3f7bf4a-f29f-4ea2-82ec-16e32eb83f03">
        <field name="cId" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="mId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="pId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="nameFirst" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="chaser" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="pName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nameLast" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="totalPremium" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <variable name="totalPremiumCost" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="RECORDS_PER_PURCHASER" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalPremium}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <group name="RECORDS_PER_PURCHASER">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{pId}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>

<datasetRun subDataset="currentDuesDataSet" uuid="c211cfad-9404-4469-af7d-e4b2df7ba716">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{list})]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

Tried references:

[How to sort fields in jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349368/how-to-sort-fields-in-jasper-report)

https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4807

Appreciate response in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve groups when adding a sort field you'll have to add sort fields for the group values before the desired sort field.

So you'd have something like this:

```
<sortField name="pId"/>
<sortField name="fieldToBeSortedOn"/>
```

Note that this will result in the data being sorted on pId, if it's not already sorted.

Comment: Sorting both fields worked. Thanks @dada67.